# Possible missing firmware update in debian 9.4

Tags: debian

I am having the following error after running `apt update` and `apt upgrade` on my server.

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/e100/d102e_ucode.bin for module e100
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/e100/d101s_ucode.bin for module e100
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/e100/d101m_ucode.bin for module e100
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8107e-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168h-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-2.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8411-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8402-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168f-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw for module r816                                                                                        9
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/phanfw.bin for module netxen_nic
cp: cannot stat '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules': No such file or dir                                                                                        ectory
cp: cannot stat '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules': No such file or dir                                                                                        ectory
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 31):

First of all, if your system is working fine, in particular all your wired and wireless network connectivity, then you don’t need to do anything — those are only warnings. Some modules will work fine without firmware in most cases (the `e100` module), others will typically require firmware; the specifics depend on exactly what hardware you have.

If you *do* have networking equipment which doesn’t work properly, then you should install the appropriate firmware. In your case, the packages you need are [`firmware-misc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-misc-nonfree) (for the `e100` firmware), [`firmware-netxen`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-netxen) (for the `netxen_nic` firmware), and [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek) (for the `r8169` firmware). To install these, you’ll have to enable [the non-free repositories](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#the-non-free-archive-area); to do so, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, find the lines which looks like

```
deb ... stretch main
```

(with a URL instead of `...`), and add `contrib non-free`:

```
deb ... stretch main contrib non-free
```

You can do this automatically by running

```
sed -i.bak 's/stretch[^ ]* main$/& contrib non-free/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

as root; this will make a backup of your original file as `/etc/apt/sources.list.bak` so you can revert if something goes wrong.

Then update your indexes and install the missing packages:

```
apt update
apt install firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-netxen firmware-realtek
```

and update your initramfs:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Its a server for my webhost, so i don't know if this is important

Comment: If your server works as-is, it isn’t important and you don’t need to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to check if a specified package is installed or not:

```
sudo apt-cache policy firmware-linux-nonfree
```

Then you to install the missing firmware run:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

After which you can run your:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should help.

Comment: Just a clarification: `apt-cache policy` won't enable anything: it only tells if a specified package is installed or not and what version(s) would be available in your currently configured repository(/ies). If there are multiple versions available, it will also identify which of those would be the "primary" installation candidate according to your current `apt` preferences.